# google recaptcha reset response variable

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am using ajax to submit a form using recaptcha verification.Now since i am using ajax the page cannot refresh.So to check whether user has clicked the recaptcha box i am using the following check

```
var recaptcha = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
if (recaptcha === "") 
{

    alert("Please check the recaptcha");

}
```

and after form submission recaptcha is reloaded using

```
grecaptcha.reset();
```

After the form submission the page is not refreshed and user may have to submit more data using same form.Now the problem is that recaptcha is loaded but var recaptcha = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val(); is returning true due to previous recaptcha submission.

How can i reset the recaptcha response variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload the google recaptcha widget after user submits invalid inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574733/how-to-reload-the-google-recaptcha-widget-after-user-submits-invalid-inputs)

Comment: No this is a different question i need to reset recaptcha response variable...

Comment: Look at the first answer, in your script do you specify `render=explicit`? I have a feeling that might solve your problem.

Comment: Can you just do something like that after form submission `grecaptcha.reset();$("#g-recaptcha-response").val("")` ?

Comment: ok that did it thanks

Comment: I added it as an answer, can you please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After your form submission, you need to reset recaptcha and then erase recaptcha response hidden input:

```
grecaptcha.reset();
$("#g-recaptcha-response").val("");
```